# Maximum with a proportion criteria

Tags: excel

I have the following Excel spreadsheet which shows products in **Column A** and their discount in **Column B**:

```
        A                 B
1   Product A           40%
2   Product B           55%
3   Product C           30%
4   Product D           30%
5   Product E           40%
6   Product F           40%
7   Product G           60%
8   Product H           60%
9   Product I           45%
10  Product J           40%
11  Product K           60%
12  Product L           40%
13  Product M           50%
14 
15 Number of Products:   13 (=Count2(B2:B14)
16   
17 Maximum Discount      ??
```

In **Cell B17** I want to display the **maximum discount** which refers to **at least 10%** of the products in the list.

Therefore, I have created the following "calculation table" which shows the proportion of each discount in the product list:

```
        B            C                          D               
    Discount    Number of products     Proportion in
                with discount          product list
22    40%           5                        38% (= 5/13)
23    45%           1                         8% (= 1/13)
24    50%           1                         8% (= 1/13)
25    55%           1                         8% (= 1/13)
26    60%           3                        23% (= 3/13)
```

Based on this calculation table I use the following formula to show the **maximum discount** with a proportion of **at least 10%**:

```
={MAX(If(D22:D26>=0,1,B22:B26,0))}
```

This works perfectly so far. However, what I want to achieve is that the "calculation table" is not necessary anymore and the calculation of the proportions and the maximum discount is done in one formula.

Do you have any idea how I could solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Aggregate()

```
=AGGREGATE(14,6,B1:B13/(COUNTIF(B1:B13,B1:B13)/B15>0.1),1)
```

[image: ![enter image description here]

Answer (score 0):

use =MODE.SNGL(B:B) formula. It will give the discount that occurred most number of times in a column